# Improve throughput of retriver in google search appliance adaptor

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am developing an Adaptor for the GSA using the Adaptor framework 4.0.

The issue I am having lies in the fact that the GSA does not call the retriever method `getDocContent()`

I have set the hostload to max 10

the Adaptor VM itself has 6 Virtual CPUs and the number of worker threads for the adaptor has been set to 64

```
server.maxWorkerThreads=64
```

Its unclear to me why the GSA does not call the getDocContent() method untill I hit the Save button on the host load schedule section of the GSA.

Answer (score 0):

Vinay,

It's going to depend on how you develop your connector and some basic infrastructure.

1) First, confirm that you have actually fed documents.  This can be confirmed under the Feeds section.
2) Second, if there are fed documents in the index diagnostics but your method is not called, then take one of the urls and test it in the crawl diagnostics realtime diagnostics via a manual fetch.
3) Confirm the port that your adaptor is running is not blocked via firewall.